# Qt3D: How to render a mesh in wireframe mode using Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt3d, wireframe

Qt3D documentation is increasing but still lacking some information especially on how to do things without Qml/QtQuick. After heavily searching the web about rendering a mesh in wireframe mode, I found a lot of helpful hints and examples that all together resulted in an example viewer that I wanted to present here as a contribution to all the guys that wrote the articles and others who may have searched similar examples.

The most helpful links were these:

[Qt basic shapes example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html)

[Qt wireframe example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-example.html)

[Qt material documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qmaterial.html)

[Qt MyCylinder example](https://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/gammaray-qt3d-geometry-example.html)

Stackoverflow question and answer about using an event filter in Qt3DWindow: [Mouse controls over Qt 3D Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986164/mouse-controls-over-qt-3d-window)

The mesh can be rotated and zoomed with the mouse.

A screenshot of the viewer

[image]

Any comments on how to improve this are welcome. Especially, I'm interested in how to write a shader program that can render front and back faces in different colors or render the colors per vertex.

And here's the code:

```
// ######### Opening the viewer #########
void MainWindow::import3dMeshInMeshViewer(QString name) 
{
    if (!m_viewer3D)
    {
        m_viewer3D = new Viewer3D(this);
    }
    m_viewer3D->sceneModifier()->addTriangleMeshCustomMaterial(name, m_meshVector);
    m_viewer3D->show();
}

// #########  Viewer class h  #########
class Viewer3D : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Viewer3D(QWidget *parent = 0);
        SceneModifier* sceneModifier() {return m_sceneModifier;}

    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev);
        void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
        void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
        void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *we);
    private:

        QPointer<Qt3DCore::QEntity> m_rootEntity;
        QPointer<SceneModifier> m_sceneModifier;
        Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow *m_view;
        QPoint m_moveStartPoint;
        QMatrix4x4 m_cameraMatrix;
};


// ######### Viewer class cpp #########
Viewer3D::Viewer3D(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    m_moveStartPoint.setX(-1);

    m_view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();

    m_view->installEventFilter(this);

    m_view->defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor(QRgb(0x4d4d4f)));

    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(m_view);
    QSize screenSize = m_view->screen()->size();
    container->setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 100));
    container->setMaximumSize(screenSize);

    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    hLayout->addWidget(container, 1);

    setWindowTitle(QStringLiteral("Mesh Viewer"));

    // Root entity
    m_rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();

    // Scene modifier
    m_sceneModifier = new SceneModifier(m_rootEntity);

    // Window geometry
    resize(parent->geometry().width() * 0.8, parent->geometry().height() * 0.8);
    move(parent->geometry().center() - QPoint(width() / 2, height() / 2));

    // Camera
    Qt3DRender::QCamera *cameraEntity = m_view->camera();

    //cameraEntity->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(22.5f, m_view->width()/m_view->height(), 0.01f, 1000.0f);
    cameraEntity->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 500.0f));
    cameraEntity->setUpVector(QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
    cameraEntity->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));
    cameraEntity->transform()->setScale(1.f);

    // Set root object of the scene
    m_view->setRootEntity(m_rootEntity);
}

bool Viewer3D::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
    {
        wheelEvent(dynamic_cast<QWheelEvent*>(ev));
        return true;
    }
    else if (ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        mousePressEvent(dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev));
        return true;
    }
    else if (ev->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        mouseMoveEvent(dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev));
        return true;
    }
    else if (ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        mouseReleaseEvent(dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev));
        return true;
    }

    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, ev);
}

void Viewer3D::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *we)
{
    Qt3DCore::QTransform* transform = m_view->camera()->transform();

    float scale = transform->scale();
    QPoint delta = we->angleDelta();
    float zoom_distance = scale * static_cast<float>(delta.y()) / 500.f;
    scale -= zoom_distance;
    scale = std::min(10.0000f, scale);
    scale = std::max(0.001f, scale);
    transform->setScale(scale);
}

void Viewer3D::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        m_moveStartPoint = ev->pos();
        m_cameraMatrix = m_view->camera()->transform()->matrix();
    }
}

void Viewer3D::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (m_moveStartPoint.x() > -1)
    {
        QPoint delta = ev->pos() - m_moveStartPoint;
        float angle = static_cast<float>(QPoint::dotProduct(delta, delta)) / 100.f;
        QVector3D axis = QVector3D(delta.y(), delta.x(), 0);

        QMatrix4x4 rotationMatrix = Qt3DCore::QTransform::rotateAround(-m_view->camera()->position(), angle, axis);

        QMatrix4x4 matrix = rotationMatrix * m_cameraMatrix;
        m_view->camera()->transform()->setMatrix(matrix);
    }
}

void Viewer3D::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (m_moveStartPoint.x() > -1)
    {
        m_moveStartPoint.setX(-1);
        m_cameraMatrix = m_view->camera()->transform()->matrix();
    }
}


// #########  Scene modifier class h #########
class SceneModifier : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        SceneModifier(Qt3DCore::QEntity* rootEntity);
        void addTriangleMeshCustomMaterial(QString name, const std::vector<Import3d::Triangle>& meshVector);

    private:
        Qt3DCore::QEntity* m_rootEntity;
};

// #########  Scene modifier class cpp #########
#include "SceneModifier.h"
#include "TriangleMeshRenderer.h"
#include "MaterialWireFrame.h"

SceneModifier::SceneModifier(Qt3DCore::QEntity* rootEntity) :
    m_rootEntity(rootEntity),
    QObject(rootEntity)
{
}

void SceneModifier::addTriangleMeshCustomMaterial(QString name, const std::vector<Import3d::Triangle>& meshVector)
{
    if (!m_rootEntity)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Mesh entity
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *triangleMeshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(m_rootEntity);
    triangleMeshEntity->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("customMeshEntity"));

    TriangleMeshRenderer *triangleMeshRenderer = new TriangleMeshRenderer(meshVector);
    MaterialWireFrame* materialWireFrame = new MaterialWireFrame();
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    transform->setScale(1.f);

    triangleMeshEntity->addComponent(triangleMeshRenderer);
    triangleMeshEntity->addComponent(transform);
    triangleMeshEntity->addComponent(materialWireFrame);

    //emit meshAdded(name, triangleMeshEntity);
}

// ######### Point and Triangle structs #########
struct Point
{
    QVector3D p; //point x, y, z
    QVector3D c; //color red, green, blue

    Point() {}

    Point(float xp, float yp, float zp)
    {
        p = QVector3D(xp, yp, zp);
        c = QVector3D(0, 0, 0);
    }
    Point(QVector3D pos, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
    {
        p = pos;
        c = QVector3D(static_cast<float>(r) / 255.f,
                      static_cast<float>(g) / 255.f,
                      static_cast<float>(b) / 255.f);
    }
};

struct Triangle 
{
    Point vertices[3];

    Triangle()
    {
    }

    Triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
    {
        vertices[0] = p1;
        vertices[1] = p2;
        vertices[2] = p3;
    }

};


// ######### TriangleMeshRenderer class h #########
class TriangleMeshRenderer : public Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TriangleMeshRenderer(const std::vector<Import3d::Triangle>& meshVector, Qt3DCore::QNode *parent = 0);
    ~TriangleMeshRenderer();
};


class TriangleMeshGeometry : public Qt3DRender::QGeometry
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TriangleMeshGeometry(const std::vector<Import3d::Triangle>& meshVector, TriangleMeshRenderer *parent);
};


// ######### TriangleMeshRenderer class cpp #########
TriangleMeshRenderer::TriangleMeshRenderer(const std::vector<Import3d::Triangle>& meshVector, QNode *parent)
    : Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(parent)
{
    setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles);
    setGeometry(new TriangleMeshGeometry(meshVector, this));
}

TriangleMeshRenderer::~TriangleMeshRenderer()
{
}

TriangleMeshGeometry::TriangleMeshGeometry(const std::vector<Import3d::Triangle>& meshVector, TriangleMeshRenderer *parent)
    : Qt3DRender::QGeometry(parent)
{
    Qt3DRender::QBuffer *vertexDataBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::VertexBuffer, this);
    Qt3DRender::QBuffer *indexDataBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::IndexBuffer, this);

    // Vertexbuffer
    QByteArray vertexBufferData;
    // Buffer size = triangle count * 3 * (3 + 3 + 3), 3 vertices per trinalge, each 3 floats for vertex position x,y,z, 3 floats normal and 3 floats color
    int bytesPerVertex = 9 * sizeof(float);
    int bytesPerTriangle = 3 * bytesPerVertex;
    vertexBufferData.resize(static_cast<int>(meshVector.size()) * bytesPerTriangle);
    char* pByte = vertexBufferData.data();
    int i = 0;
    // Indexbuffer
    QByteArray indexBufferData;
    indexBufferData.resize(static_cast<int>(meshVector.size()) * 3 * sizeof(uint));
    uint* rawIndexArray = reinterpret_cast<uint*>(indexBufferData.data());
    int idx = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < meshVector.size(); ++n)
    {
        QVector3D nt = QVector3D::normal(meshVector[n].vertices[0].p, meshVector[n].vertices[1].p, meshVector[n].vertices[2].p); 

        for (int v = 0; v < 3; ++v)
        {
            // Vertex
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = meshVector[n].vertices[v].p.x(); pByte += 4;
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = meshVector[n].vertices[v].p.y(); pByte += 4;
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = meshVector[n].vertices[v].p.z(); pByte += 4;
            // Normal
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = nt.x(); pByte += 4;
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = nt.y(); pByte += 4;
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = nt.z(); pByte += 4;
            // Color
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = meshVector[n].vertices[v].c.x(); pByte += 4;
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = meshVector[n].vertices[v].c.y(); pByte += 4;
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(pByte) = meshVector[n].vertices[v].c.z(); pByte += 4;

            // Index
            rawIndexArray[idx] = static_cast<uint>(idx++);
        }
    }

    vertexDataBuffer->setData(vertexBufferData);
    indexDataBuffer->setData(indexBufferData);

    // Attributes
    Qt3DRender::QAttribute *positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(vertexDataBuffer);
    positionAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    positionAttribute->setDataSize(3);
    positionAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    positionAttribute->setByteStride(bytesPerVertex);
    positionAttribute->setCount(3 * static_cast<int>(meshVector.size()));
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());

    Qt3DRender::QAttribute *normalAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    normalAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    normalAttribute->setBuffer(vertexDataBuffer);
    normalAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    normalAttribute->setDataSize(3);
    normalAttribute->setByteOffset(3 * sizeof(float));
    normalAttribute->setByteStride(bytesPerVertex);
    normalAttribute->setCount(3 * static_cast<int>(meshVector.size()));
    normalAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultNormalAttributeName());

    Qt3DRender::QAttribute *colorAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    colorAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    colorAttribute->setBuffer(vertexDataBuffer);
    colorAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    colorAttribute->setDataSize(3);
    colorAttribute->setByteOffset(6 * sizeof(float));
    colorAttribute->setByteStride(bytesPerVertex);
    colorAttribute->setCount(3 * static_cast<int>(meshVector.size()));
    colorAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultColorAttributeName());

    Qt3DRender::QAttribute *indexAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::IndexAttribute);
    indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexDataBuffer);
    indexAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedInt);
    indexAttribute->setDataSize(1);
    indexAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    indexAttribute->setByteStride(0);
    indexAttribute->setCount(3 * static_cast<int>(meshVector.size()));

    addAttribute(positionAttribute);
    addAttribute(normalAttribute);
    addAttribute(colorAttribute);
    addAttribute(indexAttribute);

    parent->setGeometry(this);
}
```

Comment: The traditional way of sharing your knowledge with stackoverflow is asking a question and creating an answer yourself, instead of adding the answer directly to the question. Anybody else can create a second answer or comment on your answer. At the moment, your question does not have a real question, which may result in being (wrongly) closed due to unclear what you are asking.

Comment: The wireframe shader is very inefficient. There’s no need to calculate lengths nor angles in geometry shader. See this article for more info: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/advanced-rendering/flat-and-wireframe-shading/

Comment: Bit late to the party.. but where is the material definition?

Answer (score 1):

The OP is interested on write a shader program, so its necessary to write OpenGL in Qt, right? Like in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-hellogl2-example.htm.

There is a simple shader example on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglshaderprogram.html

```
program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
    "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
    "uniform highp mat4 matrix;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = matrix * vertex;\n"
    "}");
program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
    "uniform mediump vec4 color;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = color;\n"
    "}");
```

From https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

> To draw your triangles in wireframe mode, you can configure how OpenGL
> draws its primitives via glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE).
> The first argument says we want to apply it to the front and back of
> all triangles and the second line tells us to draw them as lines. Any
> subsequent drawing calls will render the triangles in wireframe mode
> until we set it back to its default using
> glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL).

And from https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Advanced-GLSL

> The gl_FrontFacing variable tells us if the current fragment is part
> of a front-facing or a back-facing face. We could, for example, decide
> to output different colors for all back faces.