# Mouse controls over Qt3DWindow without using *Event() or eventFilter

Tags: qt, qt3d

Other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422690/qt-how-to-get-mouse-events-on-qt3dwindow), have answers that advise subclassing `Qt3DWidget` and providing overriding standard `QWidget` event handlers like `mousePressEvent()` or using a standard qt eventfilter (`installEventFilter()` is part of `QObject`). None of those answers point out a Qt3D specific way of doing this, which would most likely would involve `QAbstractCameraController`.

(I do have an answer prepared for this question but I am unable to post answers presently. If somebody else wants answer, go for it.)

Comment: I tried. Was banned instantly so I can't answer.

Comment: I have barely done anything, certainly nothing bad. Certain users on this site don't care about sharing technical information, just their reputations.

Comment: I just tried again. Same response: "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. " Catch-22.

Comment: I think the issue is I wanted to post a comment to ask where the missing "MaterialWireFrame.h" was on this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434065/qt3d-how-to-render-a-mesh-in-wireframe-mode-using-qt-c) , but since I'm not allowed to post comments, I posted it as an answer. Some people who don't even care about the topic swooped in and deleted that answer despite the original question itself being not well formed, and here we are. I might as well just make a new account...